# DateTime Struct not defined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

im trying to follow up with CatLike Coding in making a clock https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/basics/game-objects-and-scripts/

but i got stuck at "3.7 Getting the Current Time" in the following code:

```
void Awake() {  

        hoursPivot.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -30 * DateTime.Now.Hour);
    }
```

and the error was: "The name 'DateTime' does not exist in the current context [Assembly-CSharp]"

Any ideas on how to get DateTime working?

Comment: Try using `System.DateTime` instead perhaps?

Comment: Add `using System;` to the top of your program to include all types in that namespace.

Comment: yeah using System; worked for me, thanks